# Where to find pre-optimized files for Quantum Chemistry Softwares?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, crystal-structure

Many times Geometry optimization gets very time consuming ( even with access to super-computers ). I have seen some pre-optimized libraries for biomolecules like proteins that you can easily download machine optimized files from.

I use Avogadro,  GAMESS and McMolPlt for my quantum calculations.
I am thinking such libraries should exist for some complex chemical structures ( usable on softwares mentioned above ) but couldn't find any.

At this point I am specifically interested in " Hydroxyapatite Crystals ".
Does anyone know such resources ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short answer: we're building one for molecules**

In your case, you don't actually want molecules. You're mentioning crystals. In that case, I suggest the [Crystallography Open Database](http://www.crystallography.net) or if you have access, try the commercial [Cambridge Crystal Structure Database](http://webcsd.ccdc.cam.ac.uk). The COD is planning a theoretical crystal database, but I don't think it's online yet. These are experimental x-ray structures, but should be good starting structures for solid-state simulations.

For molecules, my group is building one. It's the [Pitt Quantum Repository](http://pqr.pitt.edu/) There are a few related efforts that I'm aware of.

With the PQR, you can either search through the website (even on mobile). The database is keyed by InChI keys, so if you have an existing structure you can generate the InChIKey and then get the structure, e.g.:

- [D-(-)-Morphine](http://pqr.pitt.edu/mol/BQJCRHHNABKAKU-KBQPJGBKSA-N) -> `.mol2` file at [`http://pqr.pitt.edu/api/mol2/BQJCRHHNABKAKU-KBQPJGBKSA-N`](http://pqr.pitt.edu/api/mol2/BQJCRHHNABKAKU-KBQPJGBKSA-N)

The long answer is that some commercial software vendors consider such libraries as violations of the license. No joke, I've planned this for years to augment [Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc/), but the company behind a leading program told me that they would void my license to distribute output files in this fashion.

With the rise of community and open source quantum chemistry software, this is moot. **Use programs that let you distribute output files.** What remained was:

- Gathering the 3D coordinates (i.e., a low-energy conformer) of X thousand/million molecules
- Obtaining the computer time to optimize all of them
- Devoting a server and disk space to serving them
- Having a great website to help view, browse, and search them

Comment: Thank you !  We have done some simulations in Colorado and I will be more than happy if I can contribute to that repository project.

Comment: Incidentally, we only have ~64k molecules right now at the PM7 semiempirical level and growing, so PQR may not be right for every purpose.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison, could you clarify, please. Did the "company behind a leading program" told you they would void your license if you will distribute output files created by *their* program? If so, why not choose a competing product with a much more liberal license?

Comment: @Wildcat Of course the company indicated was implying that their output files cannot be distributed. The PQR does not use this product and my group no longer uses this product.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison, you never know what to expect in terms of licensing from that "company behind a leading program". :( For me even the fact that they prohibit the distribution of the *result* obtained with their program is quite surprising. So, you pay for the program, but you don't even own the results, since you can't do whatever you want with them...

Comment: @GeoffHutchison, anyway, I wish your group good luck with the PQR project.

Comment: @Wildcat It's further ironic, since the founder of the "unmentionable program" actually wanted to have something *exactly* like PQR. We'll be adding more model chemistries for people to compare and contrast later this year.

Comment: What is your guys' favorite probability distribution?  Lorentzian?  Binomial?  Boltzmann?  It's got to be one of those, right?  No?  Which one did I leave out?

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Probably you should add info on [how to enable WebGL](https://superuser.com/questions/836832/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-my-browser) in order to access PQR, otherwise many people are not going to see structures due to the default behavior of Chrome (WebGL is disabled). And thank you very much for your hard work!

Answer (score 1):

You could try figshare.com for comp chem files and http://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/pages/Home.aspx for crystal structures.